# Back Button will not connect with action

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a back button that I want to connect to an action (Back) that is in a file (ShopController.swift). When I control+drag the button to the function, it does not connect. I read that I need to give a class to the button, but when I type one in in the side bar it automatically deletes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOmlf.png
[image: screen shot of main.storyboard and ShopController.swift]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `ShopController` as the class of the viewController to be able to connect the button action.

[image]

To do that, click on the tiny yellow icon on the top of the viewController. Then open the `Identity Inspector` and enter your class name there: